# How to change default validation error message?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to **ASP.NET MVC**, and started developing a small application. Now I have a log in form and can't find a way to change default validation error messages.

I have found two topics that suggesting something about creating a "GlobalResources" file. But I couldn't make it. I need an answer which is well explained, because I am not experienced. Any help is appreciated.

This is my code so far:

```
public class LoginModel
{

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Kullanıcı Adı:")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Şifre:")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Beni Hatırla?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's smart to first follow the basic CRUD tutorials on www.ASP.net/mvc and then ask on this forum?

Comment: Thank you for your suggest but i already read that tutorials. But now i prefer asking because all tutorials about mvc almost the same. And i can't solve most of my problems by reading them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Your Message")]
```

I would also reccomend you go through the beginner tutorials at asp.net/mvc

Comment: Oh, and I would also read into ViewModels and having a separate Metadata class for each view model. Google is your friend.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have a requirement to localise your application, you can customise the error messages by specifying the error message text in the validation attributes.

For example, your LoginModel would look something like:

```
public class LoginModel
{

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your user name")]
    [Display(Name = "Kullanıcı Adı:")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Şifre:")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Beni Hatırla?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```